# Understanding Net Metering

Tags: solar-power, electricity-generation

I have some doubts on net metering and how my solar input flows within my electric connections.

I am using grid tied split phase 240V micro-inverters. They only have L1, L2 and Ground connections and they connect directly to my main panel as the diagram shows.

Assuming this diagram is my main connection panel. Two live bars on the sides and the center would represent the Neutral. In my example, I have an unbalanced load of 4A and 2A. And assuming that my solar array is producing 2.5A per Line.

Would this be what I should expect to read from the grid? (does it make sense?)

What would be the net meter in this case? a total consumption of 1A (1.5A from L1 minus 0.5A from L2). Or would the meter be two separate numbers, 1.5A consumption and 0.5A feed?

[image]

Diagram according to answer:

[image]

Comment: You have the electrical theory part, your question is more about the details of your contract with your electricity retailer. It's likely that you're on a net use contract, but that's not guaranteed, in which case it's just the brute 5A generated, 6A used, 1A to pay for. But your contract could say just about anything so you need to look at that.

Comment: Thanks, so at least my assumptions of L1 pulling 1.5A and L2 giving 0.5A at the same time are good.

Comment: Who is your utility? They should have published rate information to help understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state:

> assuming that my solar array is producing 2.5A per line.

However, this isn't possible. The current produced by your solar array must flow in a complete circuit -- the current has to come from somewhere. So, if it is producing 2.5A, we can visualize that as 2.5A being drawn from L1 by the solar panels and pushed into L2.

## Nodal circuit analysis

Here's a different way to view the circuit and understand how the currents flow, using [nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis). In this analysis, we simplify the circuit down to "nodes", where the sum of currents into and out of each node must equal 0.

[image: 240V split phase circuit with two loads and solar supply]

The transformer is your grid supply, and VS is your solar inverter. Now to the nodal analysis:

- **At V1**, `2.5A` is flowing in from the solar, and `4A` is flowing out to the load. This means that `4 - 2.5 = 1.5A` must be flowing in from the grid.
- **At V2**, `2.5A` is flowing out to the solar, and `2A` is flowing out to the load. This means that `2 + 2.5 = 4.5A` must be flowing in from the grid.
- **At N**, `4 + 2 = 6A` is flowing in from the loads, so `6A` must also be flowing out to the grid.
- **At the grid**, we can see that `6A` is coming in from the neutral, which balances the `1.5 + 4.5 = 6A` flowing out on each phase.

## Net metering is about power, not current

In the above analysis, we determined that the loads are drawing 6A, and the grid is also supplying 6A. So does this mean that the solar isn't providing any benefit?

No, because it is still producing *power*: `P = V * I`

- Power draw at load 1: `120V * 4A = 480W`
- Power draw at load 2: `120V * 2A = 240W`
- Total power draw from loads: `480W + 240W = 720W`
- Power supply from solar: `240V * 2.5A = 600W`
- Power supply from grid: `720W - 600W = 120W`

## Why is the solar power used "before" grid power?

Your solar inverter is a grid-tied (sometimes "grid-tie") inverter, which functions by measuring the grid voltage and incrementally increasing it's output voltage (up to a set limit) as long as there is more current supply available (which will be the case whenever the sun is shining). The basic algorithm looks like this:

[image: Grid-tied inverter algorithm]

Once the algorithm gets to the end it will pause for a moment before it starts again.

Because of how the grid functions, when the local voltage is incrementally higher than the grid voltage, power will flow out from the solar array. When there is no solar energy available, the inverter voltage will simply follow the grid, allowing power to flow in.

Comment: Wow excellent explanation. Though I would still have a doubt. Since this is a split phase, Load1 and Load 2 should cancel itself as much as possible on the neutral. So the currents should actually be both travelling on the same direction. Take a look at the edited diagram. Is this more acurate?

Comment: @BenQuan the currents cancel on the neutral because they are 180 degrees out of phase (it's alternating current, so one current will be at a maximum while the other is at a minimum), but the direction of current flow will always be from line to neutral for a load.